# Guidance with proof regarding divisibility and congruence.

Tags: proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

**If 11 ∤ n, prove that $n^{5}$ ≡ 1 mod 11 or $n^{5}$ ≡ -1 mod 11 .**

I am taking my first proof writing class, and am unsure how to solve this problem. I tried using the definition of congruency to set $n^{5}$ ≡ ±1 mod 11 equivalent to $n^{5}$ - 1 = 11k, where k is any integer. Then I factored the left hand side, but I am unsure if this is leading me to the right direction. Any help, guidance, or answer would be very much so appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Have you talked about "Fermat's little theorem" in this class?

Comment: How would $n^5 \pmod{11}$ compare with $[n+11a]^5 \pmod{11}$, for any integer $a$?  What happens if you examine $x^5 \pmod{11}$ for each $x \in \{1,2,3,\cdots, 9,10\}$?

Comment: Thank you @BenGrossmann for the guidance. I think I understand how to complete the proof now. I see that making sure to specify the bounds of r is important because of the fact that 11 ∤ n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $n = 11k + r$, where $k,r$ are integers with $1 \leq r \leq 10$. Note that we have
$$
(11 k + r)^5 = \binom {5}0 (11k)^5 + \cdots + \binom {5}4 (11k)r^4 + \binom 55 r^5\\
= 11 \cdot \left[\binom {5}0 11^4k^5 + \cdots + \binom {5}4 kr^4 \right] + r^5.
$$
That is, we have $n^5 = r^5$ modulo $11$.

With that, it suffices to show that we have $r^5 \equiv \pm 1 \pmod {11}$ for each $r \in \{1,2,\dots,10\}$.

If you prefer, you could consider the set $\{\pm 1, \pm 2, \dots, \pm 5\}$.